# Theme is Enqueueing Everything in Footer

Tags: theme-development

I am developing a theme. Nothing special at the moment. In my functions.php I've added support for post thumbnails, title tag, and have one custom post type.

In my header I have wp_head() and footer has wp_footer(). The issue I'm facing is that despite all this, the standard css and javascript items are being enqueued in the footer, even the admin bar stuff.

Plugins used are:

- Gravity Forms
- Gravity Forms Survey
- Advanced Custom Fields

The stuff is still being enqueued in the footer, even when I disable these plugins.  If I switch to another theme, the stuff is enqueued in the header as expected.

At the moment, I have 4 files not counting the functions.php:

- header.php
- footer.php
- index.php
- single-survey.php

header.php (once I have this working I'll enqueue everything)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Favicons-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

    <!-- GOOGLE WEB FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- BASE CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/icon_fonts/css/all_icons_min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/skins/square/grey.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- YOUR CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- Modernizr -->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

footer.php

```
    <footer id="home" class="clearfix">
        <p>&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> My Company</p>   
    </footer>
    <!-- end footer-->

<?php wp_footer();?>

</body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
 <?php

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );


add_action('init', 'survey_custom_post');

function survey_custom_post() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Survey', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Survey', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Survey'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Survey'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Survey'),
        'new_item' => __('New Survey'),
        'view_item' => __('View Survey'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Survey'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        );
        //'taxonomies' => array('category'); 

    register_post_type( 'survey' , $args );
     }

     ?>
```

Comment: The problem is your theme, but you didn't show us how you enqueue scripts and CSS.

Comment: I'm not specifically enqueueing any scripts or css just yet. I just started setting this theme up from a purchased, static HTML template.  I added functions.php above.

Comment: What are _standard css and javascript items_ you mention?

Comment: The basic jquery and css libraries that WordPress enqueues automatically.

Comment: those are supposed to be enqueued in the footer.  Why are you trying to get them moved to the header?

Comment: Use dependencies to order your JS and CSS.   It's the 3rd parameter in both the `wp_enqueue_...` functions

Comment: Once I added all my scripts in the functions.php and enqueued them through jQuery everything started working properly.  My question now is, doesn't WordPress automatically include jQuery?